# Can Turbo LockBox use certificates from smartcard PKCS11

Tags: delphi, public-key-encryption, pkcs#11

There is nice Delphi cryptography library https://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/ It is possible to sign and very documents with this library. The question is - can this library access certificates that are stored in smarcart or can this library otherwise can use smartcard for signing and verification of documents. Maybe Turbo Lockbox with smartcard capabilities can replace the commercial XMLBlackbox product from Eldos https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-xml.php

Comment: No, it can not :))